# Limit inferior of a function sequence $f_n = \mathbf{1}_{[n,n+1]}$

Tags: measure-theory

There exists a function sequence $f_n = \mathbf{1}_{[n,n+1]}$. Thus $f_n$ oscillates between only two values specifically $0$ or $1$. Thus the limit infimum of the sequence $f_n = 0$.

However I am having trouble resolving the limit inferior of the sequence of sets generated by $f_n$.  The $\liminf$ of the set sequence is

$$\liminf A_n= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k. $$

Thus the above sequence oscillates between the two sets $\{1\}$ or $\{0\}$ and thus the intersection of which is $\emptyset \implies \bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset$.

I am unclear how to obtain the liminf $f_n$ to be $0$ using set definitions.

Comment: How do you define liminf of a sequence of function ? Usually it's defined for a sequence of sets or a sequence of numbers.

Comment: I often use it for sequences of functions by defining it elementwise, i.e. $(\liminf_{n\to+\infty}f_n)(x)=\liminf_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)$. That is useful for example in measure theory, if you consider a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ that is nonincreasing almost everywhere, then $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n$ is a priori only defined almost everywhere, and almost everywhere equal to $\liminf_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n$ which is defined everywhere.

Comment: Well $\lim\inf \mathbf{1}_{An}=\mathbf{1}_{{\lim\inf A_{n}}}$ and that is just by property of indicators  [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#Properties) . An easy but equivalent way to think about $\lim\inf$ of a sequence of sets is that it is the set of points $x$ such that $x\in A_{n}$ for all but finitely many $n$. Equivalently lim sup is the set of $x$ which are in $A_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $A_n \cap A_{n+2} = \varnothing$ for all $n$, so $$\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k = \varnothing$$ for all $n$, so $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k = \varnothing.$$

Comment: I agree with the above but if the image of the function sequence is just {0,1} then would it not be correct that the limit infimum of that set is 0?

Comment: The lim inf is not a well defined concept for a set.